# Rename multiple files with Ansible modules

Tags: ansible

I have 30 files that I need to rename by removing the version digits from the name of each file. I have tried variations of stat, file, regex filters.

For example:

```
rename aa-fileone-war-4.0.60.war to aa-fileone-war.war
rename aa-filetwo-war-4.0.62.war to aa-filetwo-war.war
rename aa-filethree-war-5.0.60.war to aa-filethree-war.war
(30 files)
```

Comment: rename 's/(-?\d\.)+/\./' *.war;

Comment: In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 5):

Get the list of files. Loop over them and rename.

Assuming the files are already deployed to the host (not on the controller):

```
- name: Get a list of files
  shell: "ls {{ path_to_files }}/*.war"
  changed_when: false
  register: results

- name: Rename the files
  shell: "mv {{ path_to_files }}/{{ item }} {{ path_to_files }}/{{ item | regex_replace('-?((\d+)\.war)+', '\.war') }}"
  with_items: results.stdout_lines
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Ryan Fisher's example -

> with_items

just did not work with ansible [2.12.2].

Here's what worked for me.

```
   - name: Get a list of files
     command: ls "{{ path_to_file }}"
     register: files_results
     changed_when: no

   - name: Rename the files
     become: yes
     command: mv  {{ path_to_file }}/{{ item }} {{ path_to_file }}/{{ name_change }}-{{ item }}
     loop: "{{ files_results.stdout_lines }}"
```